# Jboss and OPEN MQ integration

Tags: java, jboss, jms, openmq

Hello can anyone help me integrating OPENMQ (resource adaptor) into JBOSS 4.0.3 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I haven't tried this out - but look at how [ActiveMQ does it](http://activemq.apache.org/jboss-integration.html) and replace the ActiveMQ JCA jar with OpenMQ JMSRCA jar(s). I had a quick look around and this [thread on JBoss](http://community.jboss.org/thread/145861) could help - but I can't access it at the moment :(. If you figure it out - please let folks know :)

Comment: I will try to translate what ActiveMQ does to openmq.. Thanks for the info